# JPA: store OneToMany-Relationship into a map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

i have problems with storing a OneToMany-Relationship into a Map. I use JPA/Hibernate with Spring.

This is my Code:

```
@Table(name = "Room_Member", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
            columnNames = { "room", "member" }))
public class RoomMember {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room")
    private Room room;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member")
    private Member member;

    // Getters and Setters omitted
}
```

The class were i want to get the map:

```
public Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "member")
    private Map<Member, RoomMember> roomMember;

    // Getters and Setters omitted
}
```

I cant get this running, because i get a NullPointerException

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.jrLockAndRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at de.swr.eva.EventAnwendungApplication.main(EventAnwendungApplication.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.CollectionMetadataGenerator.addValueToMiddleTable(CollectionMetadataGenerator.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.CollectionMetadataGenerator.addIndex(CollectionMetadataGenerator.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.CollectionMetadataGenerator.addOneToManyAttached(CollectionMetadataGenerator.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.CollectionMetadataGenerator.addCollection(CollectionMetadataGenerator.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValueInSecondPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValue(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addProperties(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateSecondPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:875)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.__createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 16 common frames omitted
```

It works, if use ID as the key:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
@MapKey(name = "id")
private Map<String, RoomMember> roomMember;
```

But i need the Member as map key. Ofc i could build this map manually, but i think it should work automatically.

This one works as expected:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
private Set<RoomMember> roomMember;
```

Can you see my failure and give me a hint?

Best wishes!

WiZo

Comment: I think you `@MapKeyJoinColumn` should point to Member entity itself, so  `@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")`

Comment: I updated my question. It works with @MapKey and "id", but thats not what i need.

Comment: Did you try `@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")`?

Comment: is there any members in database yet when you experienced the NPE exception ?

Comment: @fg78nc yes, same error

Comment: @YouYou no, i start with an empty H2 database. The failure comes up during spring boot.

Comment: Honestly I find the code is ok unless one thing that might be the problem try removing ``(optional = false)`` from ``member``

Comment: @W-i-Z-o Please show do you persist entities.

Comment: @fg78nc i am not sure what u want to see

Comment: How you are obtaining EntityManager and how you create and persist entities.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what is it you're trying to achieve. A map in `Member` whose keys are also of type `Member`? How is this map ever going to contain more than one entry? What do you expect to happen when you put an entry into the map with a completely unrelated `Member`?

Comment: @crizzis you are right, i named the class wrong...its a room, which contains a list with members (displaye through RoomMembers)

Comment: @fg78nc i dont know, where i can get those informations from. it's not my software project. i just have a task to do with it.